# If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm getting the following warning when using [jshint](http://jshint.com/).
Why?

> If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined.

```
function demo() {
    'use strict';

    document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', test);

    function test() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `this` will indeed be `undefined` if you invoke `test` without using some way to provide a definite *thisArg*. So `test()` will give you `undefined` for the `this` value.

Comment: You'll need to use `.call()` or `.apply()` to pass `this` to the function that's being called trough indirect invocation. I don't know why strict mode does that, but it does.

Comment: But won't cause troubles when doing `demo();`, Here's a reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/nj7envm6/

Comment: It'll cause problems if you try to use `this` as an object (like trying to access properties). Not an issue in that specific function as written. Without strict mode, you're guaranteed an object.

Comment: I guess I'll have to configure jsHint to not fire those warnings?

Comment: Yeah, it's all configurable. http://jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to suppress the warning, it's better to address the root cause.

Use of `this` can be confusing, and the value of `this` can unexpectedly change when refactoring code.  Your code will be easier to read and maintain if you explicitly pass parameters.

The parameter passed to the `test()` callback is the `Event` object for the **click**:

```
function demo() {
   'use strict';
   function test(event) {
      console.log('You clicked on:', event.target.outerHTML); 
      }
   document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', test);
   }

demo();
```

Console log output will be something like:
`You clicked on: <h1 id="demo">Click Me</h1>`

The `Event` object tells you the target element that the user clicked:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

[image: Click Me]

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/24epdxbz/2

From [yehudakatz](https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/):

> The ECMAScript 5 spec says that `undefined` is (almost) always passed, but that the function being called should change its `thisValue` to the global object when not in strict mode. This allows strict mode callers to avoid breaking existing non-strict-mode libraries.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
function demo() {
  'use strict';

  var that = this; //new line

  document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('click', test);

  function test() {
    console.log(that); //print that instead of this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the scope in JS needs that instead of this, according to articles like this [Scope in js](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/)

thus, you usually will need to use

```
var that = this;
```