# p5.js returns UNDEFINED on this.instance_variable however, works when called explicitly. Please explain why. Example provided

Tags: javascript, undefined, this, p5.js, instance-variables

I have read some stack overflow and all I was able to find was that "this" was not referencing the instance variable I had in question and that it was referencing the current window. This did not help my understanding of the problem beyond parroting this back.

*I AM ABLE* to access the value when I call it explicitly and I have not found this comparison discussed or whether this is convention.  See:

```
class LetterButton {
      constructor(buttonName, text1) {
        console.log(buttonName + " created");
        this.buttonName = createButton(text1);
        this.buttonName.mousePressed(buttonFunction);
        
        function buttonFunction() {
          console.log(buttonName + "*");//<--works     
          console.log(this.buttonName);//<--does not  work UNDEFINED
        } //fn
        
        
      }//constructor
    }//end class
        
    function setup() {
      createCanvas(500, 500);
      background("beige");
      button = new LetterButton("tempButton","tempText") 
      button.buttonName.position(250,250);
    }
```

Comment: Copying this into p5.js editor, I get a warning (from jslint) on the `this`: "If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined." There is a q&a about that warning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883153/if-a-strict-mode-function-is-executed-using-function-invocation-its-this-valu#:~:text=Why%3F-,If%20a%20strict%20mode%20function%20is%20executed%20using%20function%20invocation,this'%20value%20will%20be%20undefined.&text=Because%20this%20will%20indeed%20be,to%20provide%20a%20definite%20thisArg.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the answer:

You don't have access to `this.buttonName` within a call from `this.buttonName.mousePressed()`
Though I could be wrong.